# Simplest way to do type-level `Symbol` formatting in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

Given two [`Symbol`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Symbol)s `a` and `b`, what is the simplest way to create another symbol that is equivalent to `b` but its prefix `a` stripped and the rest made lower case and slugified?

For example, how to implement this type family such that `RoutePath "Foo" "Foo_BarQux" == "bar-qux"` (the kebab case is optional)?

```hs
type family RoutePath datatype constr where 
  RoutePath datatype constr = undefined -- TODO
```

`GHC.TypeLits` does provide [`UnconsSymbol`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:UnconsSymbol) that I can use to implement this sort of thing from scratch, but it feels too low-level.  I'm wondering if there is an existing solution (a library perhaps) that I can adopt to keep code in my library smaller and simpler.

For real-word context, see [this PR](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/96) in particular the `Constructor2RoutePath` type family.

Comment: That seems like the right level of abstraction.  You're asking for string operators, so string ops on Symbols seem appropriate.

Comment: Incidentally, `UnconsSymbol` [requires GHC 9.2](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0387-char-kind.rst) - which means the library will have to drop support for GHC up to 9.0 (or use CPP to toggle the feature)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `symbols` package

I came across the [symbols](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/symbols-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Symbol-Ascii.html) package. It provides a `ToList (sym :: Symbol) :: [Symbol]` type family which enables me to process the `Symbol` as a list, however, I learned that it makes the compilation extremely slow. [Here's the code](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/96/commits/b024152071afd90592173646c7508bc85246f355) for that.

### GHC 9.2's `UnconsSymbol`

That left me with no choice but to upgrade to GHC 9.2. On the plus side, the compilation is as swift as it was before. Here's the implementation in full:

```hs
import GHC.TypeLits (ConsSymbol, Symbol, UnconsSymbol)

-- | Strip `prefix` from `symbol`. Return `symbol` as-is if the prefix doesn't match.
type family StripPrefix (prefix :: Symbol) (symbol :: Symbol) :: Symbol where
  StripPrefix prefix symbol =
    FromMaybe
      symbol
      (StripPrefix' (UnconsSymbol prefix) (UnconsSymbol symbol))

-- | Strip `prefix` from `symbol`. Return Nothing if the prefix doesn't match.
type family StripPrefix' (prefix :: Maybe (Char, Symbol)) (symbol :: Maybe (Char, Symbol)) :: Maybe Symbol where
  StripPrefix' 'Nothing 'Nothing = 'Just ""
  StripPrefix' 'Nothing ( 'Just '(x, xs)) = 'Just (ConsSymbol x xs)
  StripPrefix' _p 'Nothing = 'Nothing
  StripPrefix' ( 'Just '(p, ps)) ( 'Just '(p, ss)) = StripPrefix' (UnconsSymbol ps) (UnconsSymbol ss)
  StripPrefix' ( 'Just '(p, ps)) ( 'Just '(_, ss)) = 'Nothing

type family ToLower (sym :: Symbol) :: Symbol where
  ToLower sym = ToLower' (UnconsSymbol sym)

type family ToLower' (pair :: Maybe (Char, Symbol)) :: Symbol where
  ToLower' 'Nothing = ""
  ToLower' ( 'Just '(c, cs)) = ConsSymbol (ToLowerC c) (ToLower' (UnconsSymbol cs))

type family ToLowerC (c :: Char) :: Char where
  ToLowerC 'A' = 'a'
  ToLowerC 'B' = 'b'
  ToLowerC 'C' = 'c'
  ToLowerC 'D' = 'd'
  ToLowerC 'E' = 'e'
  ToLowerC 'F' = 'f'
  ToLowerC 'G' = 'g'
  ToLowerC 'H' = 'h'
  ToLowerC 'I' = 'i'
  ToLowerC 'J' = 'j'
  ToLowerC 'K' = 'k'
  ToLowerC 'L' = 'l'
  ToLowerC 'M' = 'm'
  ToLowerC 'N' = 'n'
  ToLowerC 'O' = 'o'
  ToLowerC 'P' = 'p'
  ToLowerC 'Q' = 'q'
  ToLowerC 'R' = 'r'
  ToLowerC 'S' = 's'
  ToLowerC 'T' = 't'
  ToLowerC 'U' = 'u'
  ToLowerC 'V' = 'v'
  ToLowerC 'W' = 'w'
  ToLowerC 'X' = 'x'
  ToLowerC 'Y' = 'y'
  ToLowerC 'Z' = 'z'
  ToLowerC a = a

type family FromMaybe (def :: a) (maybe :: Maybe a) :: a where
  FromMaybe def 'Nothing = def
  FromMaybe def ( 'Just a) = a
```

Link to [the rewrite](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/93/commits/60ffdafaedc1efcf933484046b5b117cebd1ebed).

It is not as complex as I had envisioned it when posting this question. It doesn't do the Kebab case conversion though, but I imagine that's not too complicated to achieve.